# Inheritance in java with overriden methods

Tags: java, inheritance

I got an exercise about inheritance in java:

```
public class Gran {
  private int x;
  public Gran() {
    this.x = 68; 
  }
  public int age() {
    this.x = this.x+1; return this.x; 
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Gran " + age();
  }
}

public class Dad extends Gran {
  private int x;
  public Dad(){
    this.x = 41; 
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Dad " + age();
  }
}

public class Sis extends Dad {
  private int x;
  public Sis() {
    this.x = 17;
  }
  @Override
  public int age() {
    System.out.print("Sis ");
    return super.age() - x;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Sis " + super.toString();
  }
}
```

So when I implement:

```
Gran[] family = new Gran[] { new Gran(), new Dad(), new Bro(), new Sis() };

for (Gran member : family) {
    System.out.println(member.toString());
}
```

It shows for the member `Sis : Sis Sis Dad 52`

Can someone explain why?

So this is what I thought, when the `Sis.toString()` method was called, that means:

- return `"Sis" + super.toString()`
- `super.toString() = Dad.toString() = return "Dad" + age()`

I'm confused why at this point the `age()` method from was Sis called, but not from class Gran..

I'm thankful for any help..

Answer (score 5):

When `Dad`'s `toString()` calls `age()`, the actual method that should be called depends on the runtime type of the object for which it was called. Since that object is an instance of `Sis`, the `age()` method of `Sis` is called, which also calls `Gran`'s `age()` since it contains a call to `super.age()`.

So, we have :

```
return "Sis" + super.toString()
```

where

```
super.toString()
```

returns

```
"Dad " + age()
```

but before it returns "Dad 52" (`age()` returns `69 - 17`), `age()` prints another "Sis"

so the final output is

```
Sis Sis Dad 52
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain a little more about the runtime type part ? 

Because later, when the method super.toString in Sis was called it went straight to the method in Class Gran..

Comment: @TuấnPhạm what do you mean by later? Which of the 4 instances are you referring to - new Gran(), new Dad(), new Bro() or new Sis() ?

Comment: I didnt see that you edited. By "later" i mean when the method super.age() in Sis object was called , it goes straight to class Gran, but when i called the method age() in class Dad it goes back to age() in Object Sis ?

Comment: @TuấnPhạm `super.age()` in `Sis` attempts to call the age() method in the super-class of Sis, which is Dad. Since Dad doesn't override that method, it goes directly to the age() method in Gran. When you call age() without super, it invokes the method in the class of the runtime type (Sis), unless that class doesn't override that method.

Answer (score 1):

You get the output:

> Sis Sis Dad 52

Because:
1) When you call `new Sis()` The Sis constructor is called, setting `x=17`

2) Then you call `Sis.toString()` method.

3) `Sis.toString()` calls `super.toString()`

4) super = Dad, `Dad.toString()` returns: `"Dad" + age()`, calling the age method.

This is where I think you get confused. You are expecting it to call Dad's age method because you are in Dad's `toString()` method. However, the instance you are working with is of type `Sis`. So, when you call `age()`, it will be the `Sis.age()` method that is invoked (due to the fact you have overloaded `Dad.age()`

5) `Sis.age()` method is called, **which prints "Sis"**, then calls `super.age() - x;`.

This is where it get's real ugly. Because you have defined the variable `x` in each parent and child class, **you are experiencing erasure (not a good practice)**, where the child's version of x erases the visibility of the parent's x and creates confusion when trying to understand who's x we are referencing or modifying.

Here is what happens with age/x when `Sis.toString()` is called:

1) In `Sis.toString()`, `super.toString()` is called.

2) `super.toString()` = `Dad.toString()`. In `Dad.toString()` the `age()` method is invoked.

3) Because we are type `Sis`, the `Sis.age()` method will get executed.

4) `Sis.age()` calls `super.age()` and then subtracts the value of `x`.

5) `super.age()` is invoked on `Dad`. No wait! `Dad` didn't override `age()`, so Dad's parent - `Gran.age()` get's invoked.

6) At this point in `Gran.age()`, the value of `Gran.x` is 68. In `Gran.age()`, it increments the value of x, making it 69, and returns the value.

7) So, `Gran.age` returned the value of 69 back to `Sis.age()`. The value of `Sis.x` is still 17. Remember that both Sis and Gran have their own `x` defined.

8) Finally, the `Sis.age()` method returns the result of the `Gran.age()` call (69) after subtracting the value of `Sis.x` (17) = 52.

Not very pretty. I think this clearly highlights the negative impact of erasure and defining the same variable `x` in both parent and child classes - **Just don't do it**.

Instead, define `x` in Gran as private and provide a public or protected `getX()` (would be better called 'age') method to give access to child classes. This would avoid this type of unexpected behavior.

Comment: and i understand your point about  not defining the same x but this is for testing our code understanding :D